# A open client socket, read but not write data?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client socket from which i can read (using the objectinputstream) and write (using the objectoutputstream).

Is it theoretically possible that somehow a situation is created, due unknown circumstances, where you can write but not read data from the socket using the appropriate input/output stream (or read but not write)?